# Testing angular with karma: how to set scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I got a fairly complex Angular directive, called `hy-plugin-window`, that I use inside an `ng-repeat` block ([complete directive code here](https://github.com/janesconference/hyacinth-host/blob/yo/app/scripts/directives/hyPluginWindow.js)):

```
<div ng-repeat="pluginD in pluginsDisplayed">
    <div hy-plugin-window content="pluginD" remove="remove"></div>
</div>
```

The directive uses an isolate scope, wich is bi-directionally linked to the parent's `content` member:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            content:'=',
        }
    };
```

This means that, when it's created, every directive in the list can access its unique content (which is a single member of the object `pluginsDisplayed`) and do things like:

```
scope.statusMessage = 'Loading ' + scope.content.name + '...';
```

Everything works, except that I don't know how to test it with Karma. With a fairly common test like this I hoped to manually set the scope inside of the directive:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: hyPluginWindow', function () {

    beforeEach(module('hyacinthHostApp'));

    var element, $compile, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));


  it('should do something', inject(function () {

      scope.content = {
          name: "testElement",
          id: "testElement000",
          uiType: "canvas"
      };

      element = angular.element('<div hy-plugin-window></div>');
      element = $compile(element)(scope);

      //expect(...);
  }));
});
```

But it miserably fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The first time my directive tries to access its `scope.content.name`.

Considering that I'm a testing complete newbie, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short story: change the compiled element to `<div hy-plugin-window content="content"></div>` and I think it should work.

The directive has an ISOLATE scope, which means it does not prototypically inherit from the "regular" scope.

In your test, you are defining `content` on the regular scope, but the directive itself is encapsulated - it has isolated scope and therefore does not see the `content` property defined on the regular scope.

You need to communicate that through the explicit interface of the component, which is `content` attribute.

Comment: An answer from Vojta Jina! That's awesome.